# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') with StoryShots Storybook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook, snapshot-testing, storyshots

I'm using Storyshots with storybook for snapshot testing.
Referred to the documentation here: [link1](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-storyshots), [link2](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-tests/snapshot-testing)

[The complete error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1QhC.png)

Followed all the steps here, but don't know why the error is coming :)

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/leopardslab/react-email/tree/19-add-snapshot-testing)

I have also searched on the internet for possible solutions but didn't find any solution which helps.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error when I was using this `jest.config.ts`:

```js
const config: Config = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  verbose: true,
};
```

It was because of the wrong **testEnvironment**. Using `jest-environment-jsdom` (it should be installed separately) instead of `node` fixed the problem.